# MVC Show an icon beside a valid field after form post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Been struggling hunting around the web looking for an answer to this one but to no avail.  What I want to do is show an icon beside a textbox if the field is valid.

I have a form that posts back data to the controller to be checked against some internal logic, essentially what I want is to post the form run the method to check the data and if it is valid it should show a green tick beside the field.  I have validation on the form and it is working as expected if the validation fails, just not on success.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

As for code not sure it is really relevant but it follows the structure below.

// Controller

```
private ActionResult DoSomeThing(myModelType model)
{
   //... Do checking in here
}
```

// Model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value.")]  
[StringLength(45, ErrorMessage = "Value can only have a maximum of 45 characters.")]  
public string SomeValue { get; set; }
```

// View

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.SomeValue , new { @class="control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeValue , new { @class="form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SomeValue )
```

Comment: Adding some code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The way you could achieving "Client-side custom data annotation validation" is using jQuery. Use  `$('#myelement').change(function () )` syntax for tracking changes on you element on view. Use function () for validation logic and then based on your resault use a green check mark visible beside your element you want to validate. 
Also you could some third party one like [here](http://formvalidation.io/examples/adjusting-feedback-icon-position/).